# Firemonkey Android TEdit Borderless or Flat

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe6

How to set TEdit to borderless or make it Flat in Firemonkey Android? Or any alternative input field that has borderless or flat option?

Comment: You'll need to edit the Style, preferably at runtime for a specific TEdit instance unless you want every TEdit control without borders.

Comment: Yes I want the TEdit without borders, how to do that? I already tried the method using StyleBook and clearing the background SourceLookup but still during runtime nothing happen.

Comment: Edit the style, background->opacity := 0, and you'll have borderless TEdit, just like an editable label

Comment: @edmund5, Don't change SourceLookup, just set the background object to `Visible := False` and then `Edit.Repaint`;

Comment: @LHristov If I do that I can't see the input field during runtime.

Comment: @PeterVonča Where is Edit.Repaint? I tried the Visible := False but during runtime there's still a border the bottom which is I want to remove.

Comment: @edmund5 Of course you will - you'll see the text in it and clicking on the text you'll start editing it. If the field is empty you can assign some text to it (e.g. 'Click here to enter your name') and on enter to change it to empty string.

Comment: there is already a style implemented for this.... In design view, go to your tEdit control and in the object explorer, change the stylelookup prop to transparentedit. You can drop a TRectangle, change its prop's to the color you want, then drop the transparent TEdit onto it. - All if you want to avoid dealing with styles.

Answer (score 1):

Two routes...

Styles:

use the following link to help you obtain original default style.From there you can use a copy of the style, and make changes as you wish via dropping a TStylebook and double clicking-> Loading your copied style -> after you make changes, then save and apply.. Then simply change the stylebook property for the form...

http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2013/12/31/inspecting-platform-styles-redux/

Retangles and Edits:

Make use of the already implemented styles. First drop a TRectangle to act as your TEdit. Change the fill.color/stroke.color as you want... Then drop a TEdit ontop of the rectangle and change it's Stylelookup prop to, 'transparentedit'